# how to export datagrid to pdf winform

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, datagridview

I need to export datagridview into pdf(.pdf) and word(.doc) file . so i tried below code

```
 private void ToExcelSheet(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

pass values

```
  ToExcelSheet(grd_retrn_detail, "E:/export.doc");
```

its working fine

if i pass .pdf.its creating file but i can't able to open

```
  ToExcelSheet(grd_retrn_detail, "E:/export.pdf");
```

and  i need insert data in table format in word and pdf file

where i made error?  thanks..

Comment: First file looks like a regular text file, that Word is able to open successfully. Second file is just like first file but with different extension. Each of these files have their own format.

Comment: then how to export datagrid to pdf file?